# Is a shared Ivy repository just a network drive?

Tags: java, ivy, dependency-management

I'm thinking about introducing Ivy dependency management in the company I work.

I've read the Ivy [docs](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/build-repository.html), but I'm still not sure how a shared repository (from which all developers can get libraries) is implemented technically.

Can it be just a shared network drive (under Windows) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivy supports several different protocols for the storage of repository artifacts. The details are described in the [resolvers](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html) documentation.

I use a dedicated repository manager, [nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), to host my artifacts. It saves time and provides additionally capabilities such as mirroring 3rd party repositories like [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/).